# Show fullcalendar all day event in agenda views

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a fullcalendar implementation with all day events. Is there any way to make these cover a whole day in the agenda views, rather than only being shown in the all day slot?

```
Example:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c1gomowa/

Answer (score 1):

There is a easy way to show only events of the day instead showing all showing blank spaces.

just use this --> basicDay in your header.

header:

```
  {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,basicDay'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the event start to 00:00:00, and end: 23:59:59
that should make it span the whole day (set allDay: false).

```
$("#FullCalendar").fullCalendar({
    defaultView: "agendaWeek",
    eventLimit: true,
    events: [
                {
                    title: 'Event',
                    start: '2015-01-19 00:00:00',
                    end: '2015-01-19 23:59:59'
                }
    ],
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    }
})
```

Comment: I have tried this but using background events means this approach leads to the event not being visible in the month view?

Comment: that same event should show just fine in the month view. put that code in your jsfiddle; it works just fine in any view

Comment: Thanks, but here's an example using your suggestion with rendering: 'background' set. It does not show in month view in this situation - http://jsfiddle.net/c1gomowa/7/

Comment: what are you trying to do with it in the 'background'? as per docs, you can't do what you want if you set background rendering. you'll have to customize fullCalendar source code to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to blank off days where events can not be added. Individual days, so setting which days to show in fullcalendar would not work. Will look in to the source, thanks